# Get dimensions of node

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a little program in JavaFX and try to follow the the MVC model.
I have a class that contains information, 2 lists of strings and a title, which functions as the model. I have an other class which is the visual representation of the information and is the view. I would like to get the dimensions (height and width), preferably in the information class.

I bind the height and width property I created in the Information class to those in the Visual class. My problem is, I want these height and width immediately after they're rendered, but it seems they're not updated immediately. How do I solve this?

```
public class Information {

    private String title;
    private List<String> info1;
    private List<String> info2;

    private SimpleDoubleProperty height = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private SimpleDoubleProperty width = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public List<String> getInfo1() {
        return info1;
    }

    public List<String> getInfo2() {
        return info2;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height.get();
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty heightProperty() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height.set(height);
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width.get();
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty widthProperty() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width.set(width);
    }
}

public class Visual extends VBox {

    public Visual(Information i) {
        getChildren().add(new Label(i.getTitle()));

        for (String s1: i.getInfo1()) {
            getChildren().add(new Label(s1));
        }

        for (String s2: i.getInfo2()) {
            getChildren().add(new Label(s2));
        }

        i.widthProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        i.heightProperty().bind(heightProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use two `ListView`s instead of `VBox`. If your `info1` and  `info2` lists will have huge size then you will create to many `Labels`. It is very unefficient. `ListView` will create only visible labels and reuse them when needed.

Comment: @MBec I used a Vboxes because they don't contain a lot of labels and it was a little bit simpler and shorter than the ListView, but I agree the ListView would probably be better for a larger list.